# How to know the central time in .NET

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a console app on the server that I need to run between 8 am to 5pm central time on weekdays. I have a batch file that invokes the console app and scheduled it to run every hour from Mon-Fri for a period of 12 hours. This means that the app would be running 12 hours instead of 10.  To overcome this problem...I want to do a simple check in .NET code that checks if the time is between 8 am to 5 pm central time..

How do I know if the time is between 8 am to 5 pm central time in .NET.

Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var CSTNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"));
if(CSTNow.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(8,0,0)  && CSTNow.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(17,0,0))
{
/* Do something */
}
```

Comment: How do we get time 8 AM central time into a variable